# Can Yahoo! Mail accounts use a 2FA code generator authenticator app?

Tags: security, account-management, yahoo-mail, yahoo, yahoo-account

I would like to set up 2-factor authentication for an old Yahoo! account and `@yahoo.com` email address.

Specifically the "code generator"-type [Time-based One-Time Password (TOTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) based on [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) implemented by client apps such as Google Authenticator, Authy, 1Password, etc.

Yahoo! account settings seem to only mention "Phone Number" for SMS texts or a hardware "Security Key".

Can Yahoo! accounts use code generators for 2FA/MFA authentication?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an authenticator app now, but if you've already set up "2-step verification" with a phone number, you will need to disable it and set it up again. The instructions for setting up an authenticator app can be found here: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN5013.html

Here are the current steps described in the knowledge base article linked above:

> Note: You may not see this option as it isn't fully available yet.
>
> 1. Sign in to your Account Security page.
> 2. Next to "2-Step Verification," click Turn on 2SV.
> 3. Click Get started.
> 4. Select Authenticator app for your 2-step verification method.
> 5. Click Continue.
> 6. Scan the QR code using your authenticator app.
> 7. Click Continue.
> 8. Enter the code shown in your authenticator app.
> 9. Click Done.

Comment: Great find! Was this just added? Are you the developer!?

Comment: I was just looking to do the same thing myself and happened to find your question before I found the instructions, so I thought I'd come back and answer. I'm sure the only option was to use SMS when I initially set up 2-step verification on my account, but I'm not sure when they added the option to use an authenticator app. I think it must have been fairly recent.